# Get the specific number from string in view of beginning whole number in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I am attempting to get the Match an esteem from a string. I have to get two sorts of numbers from the given string. Number begins from 5 took after by 6 digits. ex(`5******`) and begins from 1 took after by 5 digits(`1*****`).

I use the following regexex:

```
(5)[\d]{6} 
(1)[\d]{5}
```

Code:

```
  var sampleId5 = Regex.Match(input, @"(5)[\d]{6}");
  if (sampleId5.Success)
  {
      string test = sampleId5.Value;
  }

  var sampleId1 = Regex.Match(input, @"(1)[\d]{5}");
  if (sampleId1.Success)
  {
      string test1 = sampleId1.Value;
  }
```

Issue here is, whether I pass `5106542` it is returning both coordinated results.

I attempted this `(^5)[\d]{6}` too. be that as it may, its not working.

I require just `5*****`*. Any help would be truly valued.

Comment: what's wrong with `(^5)[\d]{6} = ^5\d{6}`?

Comment: Not sure as the question is ambiguous: are you looking for [`\b(5\d{6}|1\d{5})\b`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb(5%5cd%7b6%7d%7c1%5cd%7b5%7d)%5cb&i=5106542) with `Regex.Matches`? See [this demo](http://ideone.com/TpMlHz).

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to validate strings that are entirely numeric?  Sometimes just `10000 <= tryParseInt(input) <= 19999` with is a better solution.

Comment: Any feedback? Please precise your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your expressions do not make any requirements about the placement of the match, so they find matches in the middle.

If you need to find stand-alone numbers that fit your criteria, add `\b` on both sides of your expressions to ensure that there are no letters/digits on either side:

```
var sampleId1 = Regex.Match(input, @"\b(1)[\d]{5}\b");
//                                   ^^          ^^
```

Now that the expression considers only isolated sequences of digits, `5106542` is not going to match, because the matched sequence is in the middle.

Comment: Thanks Buddy.! Its working. Sorry for the late acknowledgement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
^(5\d{6}|1\d{5})

You should get the whole number, then just check the first digit.
However, you might want to add a "$" or a \b (as dasblinkenlight pointed out) at the end of the regex.